# How to prove that $\lim_{n \to +\infty}{x_{n+m}}=x$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{n \to +\infty}{x_n}=x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Im trying to prove that $\lim_{n \to +\infty}{x_{n+m}}=x$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\lim_{n \to +\infty}{x_n}=x$ . I already proved $\lim_{n \to +\infty}{x_n}=x$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{n \to +\infty}{x_{n+m}}=x$ using the definition of convergence, but I'm stuck trying to prove it the other way around. $x_n$ is just a real sequence.

My proof for $\lim_{n \to +\infty}{x_n}=x$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{n \to +\infty}{x_{n+m}}=x$ went like this:

$\lim_{n \to +\infty}{x_n}=x$ means that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ an $N \in \mathds{N}$ bigger than zero exists so that for all $n > N$ $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$. Considering $n + m > n > N$ this means that $|x_{n+m}- x| < \varepsilon$ so.
$\lim_{n \to +\infty}{x_n}=x$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{n \to +\infty}{x_{n+m}}=x$

Comment: I think is $n \to \infty$ and not $x$

Comment: Intuitively: adding $m$ terms to the beginning of a sequence doesn't change anything about convergence

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could post/summarize your proof for the first part. As far as I can see, the two proofs are extremely similar.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks! I edited that out, I also added my proof for the first part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+m} = x$. Then, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N_0$ such that if $n > N_0$ then $|x_{n+m} - x| < \varepsilon$. If we define $N := N_0 + m$ then we see that if $n > N$ then $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$.